# javaScript is taking the browser date ? how can i change it?

Tags: javascript, datetime, browser

I am currently working on a project which use dates, and I need to prevent the user from using previous dates, (exmp: like making a flight reservation you can't make a reservation for a previous date), the problem is when I change my computer date I can bypass this control because JavaScript uses the browser date how can I manipulate that?

I want the user to use either the server date not the browser or a good way to prevent the user from entering a previous date even if he change his system date.

Comment: Send the server date to the client?

Comment: @MarkBaijens it is a solution, but every time I am going to need a date I make a call to the server and that's not a good practise right?

Comment: Depends how important it is that the client has the correct date. It has it's downsides but if you want reliable data then a source that is under your own control is (or should be) the most reliable. Maybe you can send the date with the initial page load so you don't need to a async request for it and compare it with the browser time to check for differences. I don't know your usecase but I would just validate it at server side when submitting the data in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Get it from the internet using a api like [World Time API](http://worldtimeapi.org/).

Example request:

```
http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/London
```

Result:

```
{  
   "week_number":20,
   "utc_offset":"+01:00",
   "utc_datetime":"2019-05-14T14:40:40.532979+00:00",
   "unixtime":1557844840,
   "timezone":"Europe/London",
   "raw_offset":0,
   "dst_until":"2019-10-27T01:00:00+00:00",
   "dst_offset":3600,
   "dst_from":"2019-03-31T01:00:00+00:00",
   "dst":true,
   "day_of_year":134,
   "day_of_week":2,
   "datetime":"2019-05-14T15:40:40.532979+01:00",
   "abbreviation":"BST"
}
```

#### But always prepare for users who want to make harm in your system, so dont forget to check the time in the backend!!